# When creating a new object in backbone.js my attributes save as nil

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

So everytime i create a new affiliate it saves into the database but with no name. I can't for the life of me figure this out.

```
    class Shop.Views.AffiliatesNew extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['affiliates/new']

  events:
    'submit .form-container': 'addAffiliate'

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)
    @collection.on('add', @render, this)

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(affiliates: @collection))
    this

  addAffiliate: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    @collection.create({
      name: $('#first').val()
      })


    <input type="text" name="name" id="first"/> <br />
          .form-title 


          .submit-container
            <input id="affiliate-button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Is the value getting posted from the browser in the request?

Answer (score 0):

Try using classes instead of IDs to represent your input fields. You may have another `#first` elsewhere on the page which may cause only the first one to be found (varies by browser).

You can also scope within the view by using `this.$el.find(<selector>)`

Comment: No other #first id on the page. It's something trivial and I just can't seem to put a finger on it

Comment: when i do console.long($('#first').val()) I get the proper string. It just doesn't save with the database. It just saves as nil.